# memoir decorative rules in heading

Tags: header-footer, memoir, ornamental-fonts

I borrowed some code from [showcase-of-beautiful-typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/74609#74609)

and try to do same decoration using `memoir` class without `fancyhdr`

Here is MWE:

```
            \documentclass[twoside,12pt,english]{memoir}
            \usepackage{babel}
            \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
            \usepackage{color}
            \definecolor{marron}{RGB}{60,30,10}
            \definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,0,80}
            \definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{80,80,80}
            \definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,80,0}
            \definecolor{darkgray}{RGB}{0,80,0}
            \definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{80,0,0}
            \definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.97,0.97,0.97}
            \usepackage{lettrine}
            \input Acorn.fd
            \newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Acorn}{xl}{n}}
            \usepackage{fourier-orns}
            \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
            \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
            \usepackage{etoolbox}
            \makeatletter
            \patchcmd{\makeheadrule}
            {\@width #2\@height #3 }
            {\color{darkgray}\raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{\leafright} \hrulefill \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{~~~\decofourleft \decotwo\decofourright~~~} \hrulefill \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{ \leafleft}%
            }
            {}
            {}
            \makeatother
            
            \nouppercaseheads
            \makepagestyle{myruled}
            
            
            \makeevenhead{myruled}{\thepage}{}{}
            \makeoddhead{myruled}{}{\rightmark}{\thepage}
            \makeevenfoot{myruled}{}{}{} 
            \makeoddfoot{myruled}{}{}{}
            \makeatletter % because of \@chapapp
            \makepsmarks{myruled}{
                \nouppercaseheads
                \createmark{chapter}{both}{nonumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
                \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
                }
            \makeatother
            \pagestyle{myruled}
            \begin{document}
            \chapter{Test}
            Test. \newpage
            \section{Plant\ae}
            Test section. 
            \newpage
            Test. 
            \end{document}
```

If i move decoration code in the first `{}` nothing is displayed....How can i redefine `memoir`'s builtin `hrule`?

output:

[image]

p.s.
same question about `makefootrule`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work

```
        \renewcommand\myruledheadrule{%
          \color{darkgray}\raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{\leafright}%
          \hrulefill%
          \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{~~~\decofourleft%
            \decotwo\decofourright~~~} \hrulefill%
          \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{ \leafleft}%
          \vskip-24pt
        }
```

you may need to  change the `\vskip-24pt` part. The resulting height of the rule should end up as zero.

`\makeheadrule{name}{}{}` just defines `\nameheadrule`